# How to Find the Windows default browser using autoit

Tags: autoit

i had tried following code and but iam getting null

```
$myDefaultBrowser = RegRead("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Clients\StartMenuInternet", "(Default)")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can find the default browser by replacing "(Default)" with ""

```
$myDefaultBrowser = RegRead("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Clients\StartMenuInternet", "")
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is another one:

```
#include <APIRegConstants.au3>
#include <WinAPIReg.au3>
ConsoleWrite(_getDefaultBrowser() & @crlf)

Func _getDefaultBrowser()
    Return _WinAPI_AssocQueryString(".html", $ASSOCSTR_EXECUTABLE)
EndFunc   ;==>_getDefaultBrowser
```